# GUI Dropdown Full Width According to Screen Resolution

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to build GUI programatically according to JSON Object and stacking each dropdown on top of each other. This is what I am trying to achieve.[image]

And this is the my current code.

```
btnRect = newDropdown.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
btnRect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Screen.width, 54);
```

But what really happen is, the my dropdown width is larger than the canvas width. What I can do to fix it?

**Edited**

My Current View

[image]

Comment: You should not bother yourself with placement and dimensions. Unity has built-in components to layout your UI elements : [Vertical Layout Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html). Create an empty taking your whole Canvas, put a Vertical Layout Group and attach your instantiated dropdowns has children of the empty with the layout group.

Comment: I can't get it to work somehow. On the main canvas, how should I setting my Canvas Scaler ?

Comment: The canvas scaler should not be a problem. UI Layout is quite hard to master. The empty should be anchored  to (0,0) ; (1,1) with left, top, right and bottom set to 0. The vertical Layout Group should have : `ChildControlsSize` : (true, false) `Child Force Expand` : (true, false).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I have manage to stack every dropdown on top of each other. Except that the width is not full screen. Is it something I have to do programatically ?

Comment: No coding needed. What is the render mode of your canvas? (Screen space / World space) Are you sure the empty with the Vertical layout covers your whole canvas? Also, make sure you have specified `0` to the padding values of the vertical layout.

Comment: My render mode is Screen Space-Overlay, and the empty gameobject which have VerticalLayoutGroup is covering my whole canvas. and my padding value is 0. I will show the current view in my post under edited.

Comment: Are you sure the dropdown elements don't have any "padding" ? Please, edit the question and provide the rectTransform of your elements.

Comment: I think I have fix it. I have no idea why by all of my dropdown local scale went to 0.75, so I set everything back to 1 programatically.